# entity framework inserting a many to many relationship across multiple contexts

Tags: ado.net, entity-framework-4

I have an Events table and a PaymentTypes table which are linked by Events_PaymentTypes join table. EF allows me to add an entry into the join table by doing Event.PaymentTypes.Add(PaymentType).  However, I'm getting the PaymentTypes from one context and doing the add operation in another context.  If I detach the PaymentType first, it creates a new record in the PaymentTypes table, which is not what I want. How can I get around this?

Comment: Can you post some small code snippet showing what you are actually doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out.  I wasn't attaching it to the other context before adding it.